# trying to turn MySql database rows into links so users can choose what they want to view

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm building a website that allows users to share information using a form.  The form sends the input to a MySQL database which has a table for each category with 3 columns.  I want to be able to allow the users to choose a category and all the rows appear as links so they can pick and view. I created another page to display the input but it will only display 1 row of information.  I did some research about storing the whole form but I read it wasn't a good idea to store a file.  I'm at a stand still and cant figure out what to do next.  Can anyone recommend  a tutorial or have any advice on this.  Here is the code I'm using to display the info to the user.

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","")
or die("no connection");
$db_select=mysql_select_db("smqr",$connection)
or die("no connection to db");

$query= ("SELECT * FROM seafood");
$result=mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());

while
($row =mysql_fetch_array($result)):
 $recipe=$row['recipe'];
 $usrtext=$row['usrtext']; 
 $usrtxt=$row['usrtxt'];
 endwhile;
 ?>

 <body bgcolor="#ffccff">
<table align="center"  width="780" height="100%"  bgcolor="lightgrey" border="1">   
<thead>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th height="220">
<img src="seafoods.jpg" width="100%" height="220" /></th></tr>
<tr>
<th><h3>Recipe Name</h3> <p align="left">
<?php echo "$recipe" ?></p></th></tr>
<tr>
<th><h3>Ingrediants and Measurements </h3>
<p align="left"><?php echo $usrtext ?></p></th></tr>
<tr>
<th><h3>Instructions </h3>
<p align="left"> <?php echo $usrtxt ?></p></th>
</tr>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your table inside while loop to display all the records and better use  `{}` for while loop.

```
while($row =mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$recipe=$row['recipe'];
$usrtext=$row['usrtext']; 
$usrtxt=$row['usrtxt'];
?>
<table align="center"  width="780" height="100%"  bgcolor="lightgrey" border="1">   
<thead>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
.....
......
</tr>
</table>
<?php
 }
 ?>
```